# TFS 2015 Test case association with test method

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, tfs-2015

I created a test case (work item) in Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online) and associated it with an automated test.

1. Can I run the automated test from the web UI ?
2. When I run the dll of the solution from build definition, the test is running,
   but how can I get the information about the test case thats associated with the test ?

Answer (score 0):

1 - You can run a build which runs your tests.  I don't think you can run individual tests.

2 - You can access the test case iteration data using the [DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.datarow.aspx) property on the TestContext.

```
testContextInstance.DataRow["Name"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant run individual automated Test Cases in the Web yet, but you can run them from Microsoft Test Manager.

On the "run" tab in MTM you can select any automated test cases and create a test run for a  particular build (where it gets the DLL) and a  particular  environment (where that build is deployed).